# Select required data in sql WHERE conditon

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table like

```
 EID         Name            Desc

  1           DMK            Den (Obsolete)
  2           KMPL            K descforce
  3           SFFSS           system force (Obsolete)
  4           QEMPL           Yes
  5           BGRNK           BoardGMP
  6           JIGG            J G (obsolete)
```

How do i retrive EID,Name WHERE Desc is not (Obsolete). Result table looks like

```
  EID         Name            Desc

  2           KMPL            K descforce
  4           QEMPL           Yes
  5           BGRNK           BoardGMP
```

How to specify that in WHERE clause of sql query?

Comment: Doesn't `NOT LIKE` do what you need?

Comment: use NOT LIKE '%Obsolete%'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the `not like` clause.  In MS Access, this uses `*` as a wildcard, so the query is:

```
select t.*
from table as t
where [desc] not like "*obsolete*";
```

I forget if `like` in Access is case sensitive, so you might need:

```
select t.*
from table as t
where lcase([desc]) not like "*obsolete*";
```